# Flight With KLM to Santiago with a stop in Buenos Aires

Tags: stopovers, chile, klm, buenos-aires, santiago-de-chile

I have a flight with KLM from Amsterdam to Santiago, Chile with a stop in Buenos Aires.

I am wondering how this stop affects me. I will not be transferring to another aircraft, this flight simply stops in Buenos Aires then continues to Chile.

Do I remain on the plane seated or do I get off and wait in the lobby to reboard again?

Is there a special route in the airport that these passengers take if we do have to deboard?

Or is it simply following signs to connecting flights just as any other connection flight would be?

Answer (score 2):

You should follow the instructions given to passengers by the crew. Most likely you'll remain inside the aircraft.

Answer (score 1):

I've taken a couple of flights where there is a intermediate stop.

On one occasion, I was heading to the plane's final destination (St Lucia) and there was an announcement asking us to stay on the plane if this stop (Antigua, IIRC) wasn't your destination.  On the return to London, the plane stopped again and more passengers boarded.  I don't recall if anybody got off or even if there was an announcement about that.

On the other occasion, I was heading to the plane's intermediate stop (Bangkok) and got off there.  Other passengers stayed on board and carried on to the plane's final destination (Kaohsiung).  On the return, there were already passengers on the plane, but I couldn't tell if they had just boarded earlier than me or had come from the plane's original departure point.

On other occasions, I've had to change planes (Buenos Aires is one of these) and of course you get off and follow the connections signs.

Answer (score 0):

How long is the stop over?

Generally what happens is, you will be asked to disembark from the aircraft, wait in the transit hall, then re-embark onto the aircraft. While you wait in the transit hall - they will clean the aircraft, stock up on food, etc.